# Piping fragments of a document through various commands

Tags: shell, command-line

I want to send, maybe using escape sequences such as `$$$`, fragments of an article through various commands, possibly with modifiers. The stdin would be replaced by the corresponding stdout. (Deleting the very special modifier should be simple enough with sed, if necessary.)

I believe I can do it with python... but I was wondering if there is that special UNIX tool or technique that I don't know about that might do 90% of the trick elegantly.

To be more concrete, consider the following document:

```
$$$ figlet -f script
Title
$$$

Now it's time to visualize the cosine function:

$$$ gnuplot
set terminal dumb
plot cos(x)
$$$

Finally, a simple directed graph:

$$$ graph-easy
digraph G {
A -> B;
}
$$$
```

After running my program I would get:

```
 ______     _
(_) |o     | |
    |  _|_ | |  _
  _ ||  |  |/  |/
 (_/ |_/|_/|__/|__/


Now it's time to visualize the cosine function:


    1 ++----------***--+---------------****---------------+--***----------++
      +          *   * +               * +*               + *cos(x) ****** +
  0.8 ++        *    *                *    *                *    *        ++
      |         *     *               *     *               *    *         |
  0.6 ++        *     *              *      *              *     *        ++
      |        *       *             *      *             *       *        |
  0.4 ++       *       *             *       *            *        *      ++
      |       *        *            *        *            *        *       |
  0.2 ++      *         *           *         *           *        *      ++
      |       *         *          *          *          *         *       |
    0 ++      *          *         *          *          *          *     ++
 -0.2 ++     *           *         *          *         *           *     ++
      |      *            *        *           *        *            *     |
 -0.4 ++    *             *       *            *       *             *    ++
      |     *             *      *              *      *             *     |
 -0.6 ++    *             *      *               *     *              *   ++
      |    *               *    *                *    *               *    |
 -0.8 *+  *                 *   *                *   *                 *  +*
      +* *             +    *  *         +        *  *    +             * *+
   -1 +***-------------+-----**----------+---------**-----+-------------***+
     -10              -5                 0                5                10


Finally, a simple directed graph:

+---+
| A |
+---+
  |
  |
  v
+---+
| B |
+---+
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thanks a lot, and cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) & [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (for *here-string* `<<<` feature ):

```
awk '
    /^\$\$\$/{
        sub(/\$\$\$/, "")
        cmd=$0
        next
    }
    { arr[cmd]=arr[cmd] $0";"}
    END{
        for (a in arr) {
            if (a ~ ".") {
                exe=sprintf("%s", a " <<< \042" arr[a] "\042" )
                system(exe)
            }
            else{
               print arr[a]
            }
        }
    }' file
```

Output:

```
    1 ++----------***--+---------------****---------------+--***----------++
      +          *   * +               * +*               + *cos(x) ****** +
  0.8 ++        *    *                *    *                *    *        ++
      |         *     *               *     *               *    *         |
  0.6 ++        *     *              *      *              *     *        ++
      |        *       *             *      *             *       *        |
  0.4 ++       *       *             *       *            *        *      ++
      |       *        *            *        *            *        *       |
  0.2 ++      *         *           *         *           *        *      ++
    0 ++      *         *          *          *          *         *      ++
      |       *          *         *          *          *          *      |
 -0.2 ++     *           *         *          *         *           *     ++
      |      *            *        *           *        *            *     |
 -0.4 ++    *             *       *            *       *             *    ++
      |     *             *      *              *      *             *     |
 -0.6 ++    *             *      *               *     *              *   ++
      |    *               *    *                *    *               *    |
 -0.8 *+  *                 *   *                *   *                 *  +*
      +* *             +    *  *         +        *  *    +             * *+
   -1 +***-------------+-----**----------+---------**-----+-------------***+
     -10              -5                 0                5                10

;;;Now it's time to visualize the cosine function:;;;Finally, a simple directed graph:;;
+---+
| A |
+---+
  |
  |
  v
+---+
| B |
+---+
 ______     _       
(_) |o     | |     o
    |  _|_ | |  _   
  _ ||  |  |/  |/   
 (_/ |_/|_/|__/|__/o
                   /
```

It's not a big deal to modify it a bit to be 100% compliant with your demand.